# Get all SharePoint News from Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to get news from SharePoint online using Microsoft Graph?

On [this page](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2016/09/26/enriching-the-mobile-and-intelligent-intranet-with-team-news-apps-for-android-and-windows-and-more/?eu=true) from Microsoft they announce that:

> If you use the SharePoint app on iOS, you get the first look at the
>   mobile experience of team news. When you tap the News tab, you will
>   see a list of aggregated news using the intelligence of the Microsoft
>   Graph from the sites you work in, the sites you follow and the sites
>   your colleagues work in. SharePoint mobile on iOS gives you one place
>   to catch up on the news from across your intranet. That’s your news in
>   your pocket!

But when looking in [Microsoft Graph documentation for SharePoint](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/sharepoint), it doesn't seem to be any APIs for fetching aggregated news and other items from SharePoint? Am I missing something or is the the office blog just marketing talk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph is still a work in progress.  They're probably using the search api to surface news on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks. Which Search API are you referring to? I only see the one for Drive. Not any SharePoint or general one?

Comment: SharePoint search. My guess is that they're using "/_api/search" and specifying a content type within the scope of a site collection.

Comment: Aha, so not graph but SharePoint API. So much for "Intelligence of the Microsoft Graph" :-)